# Returning input to pristine from dirty without using form Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to revert to pristine from dirty on cancel press in my project but have been unable to. I am not using angular forms so I was wondering is there another way to do this

```html
<div class="patient-name ui-g-12 pad-dets" >
        <div class="ui-g-5 exp-title lrg-scr al-title"
             style="text-align:left !important">
                  Nombre:
        </div>

        <input  class="ui-g-5 ui-md-7 ui-sm-12 phone-inf-w form-control"
                id="disabled-input"
                [(ngModel)]="firstName"
                type="text"
                required
                size="30"
                required="required"
                pInputText/>

    </div>
```

This is a small snippet of what I have currently.

Comment: save the first value of `firstName` to another variable then when you `cancell press` do `this.firstName = this.firstNameBackup;`

Comment: How exactly are you _not_ using angular forms when the ngModel directive is part of the angular forms module? https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: the first name is blank i do this already when reseting the form. I set it to blank but the input remains red bordered until i refresh the page. ive used ngmodel is thousands of places outside of forms

Comment: `ngModel` turns the input into an `ngControl` and the form that it's part of into an `ngForm`. You are using Angular forms, you just aren't using reactive forms or the `FormBuilder`. Pristine, touched, etc. are part of Angular forms and wouldn't exist otherwise. That being said, you can just `ViewChild` the `NgControl` on the input or the input itself and control its state with `AbstractControl` methods, like `markAsPristine`.